# Weighted multinomial logistic regression for proportions in multiple outcome categories

Tags: r, regression, statsmodels, multinomial-logit

In my data, I have $N$ users, and for each we measure at $t_i, i\in[1,..,N]$ different times whether it belongs to one of *k* categories (let's say *A*, *B*, and *C*). The data columns looks like this:

```
user_id    frac_in_A    frac_in_B  frac_in_C  total_measurements   several_categorical_and_cardinal_predictors
```

The aim is to generate a model that predicts the fractions (in this case, `frac_in_A` and `frac_in_B`, because `frac_in_C` can be derived from the other two). From what I've read, I need to use multinomial **weighted** logistic regression with this. However, it seems `statsmodels` doesn't allow weighted multinomial logistic regression, and I am a total beginner in R and there seem to be several modules dealing with multinomial logit. I am hoping to use `rpy2` as I am more versed in Python and hope to port it over. Can anyone help? Thank you!